# Enable Seamless mode using AxInterop.MSTSCLib

Tags: activex, remote-access, remote-desktop

I have an application that use AxInterop.MSTSCLib activeX to create remote connection to another PC similar to the following application:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

My question, is there an option that I can config to connect the PC in seamless mode?

Comment: This is entirely up to you, you create the "seam".  It you want to run it full-screen then simply set the Dock property on the control to Fill and your form's FormBorderStyle to None, WindowState to Maximized.  Easy peasy.

Comment: this is not what I mean in seamless, seamless mode mean (Windows kiosk mode): empty desktop, no taskbar, you see only the app running in the session (start app)

Comment: Of course, that's what "full screen" means.  Haven't tried it?  Why not?  It takes 10 seconds.

Comment: It not make science to me, I want to see TARGET PC that I connect to it remotely using this active without taskbar and empty desktop, and only the application running on the TARGET PC, I'm not talking about not seeing MY PC taskbar. I want to connect to PC remotely and the remote PC in Windows kiosk mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is over a year old but I am assuming this is what you want to do:

```
        rdp.Server = "Server";
        rdp.UserName = "Username";
        rdp.Domain = "Domain";
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
        secured.ClearTextPassword = User.Password;

        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.ConnectionBarShowMinimizeButton = false;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.ConnectionBarShowPinButton = false;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.ConnectionBarShowRestoreButton = false;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.EnableWindowsKey = 0;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.RedirectClipboard = true;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.RedirectDrives = true;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.RedirectPrinters = true;
        rdp.AdvancedSettings8.SmartSizing = true;
        rdp.SecuredSettings3.StartProgram = "LaunchApp Path";
        rdp.Connect();
```

In addition follow what @Hans Passant suggested above..